# Run interactive local script on remote machine using docker-machine ssh

Tags: ssh, docker-machine

I have a local interactive (ruby) script, `script.rb`. I have a dockermachine, `aws01`. (The script pulls large files from point A, does some simple processing, and uploads them to S3).

Unfortunately, this incantation doesn't seem to do it:

```
docker-machine ssh aws02 -t ruby < script.rb
```

It runs the script, but not interactively :/

Any ideas how to do this in a single command?

(You could copy the script over and run it, you could grab the docker-machine's info and plug it into SSH with the -t flag... but I don't know how to do that in a single command)

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the script itself on the standard input of the remote command (`<` redirection) so there is no other channel left for you to interact with the script.

In short, it is not possible with a single command. I would go with two:

```
docker-machine ssh aws02 "cat > script.rb" < script.rb
docker-machine ssh aws02 -t "ruby script.rb"
```